# Drawing a Random Walk in Java with Arrays

Tags: java

I'm trying to "draw" the path of the following "Random Walk," by defining points using arrays and then connecting them with a line on each time step. I've tried just about everything but the lines simply don't draw in... The screen is blank. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Obviously, the following makes use of the JFrame library. My code follows:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class RandomWalk extends JPanel {

public static void main(String args[]) {

    //The number of steps the algorithm iterates over.
    int num = 2000;

    //The length of a line.
    int range = 50;

    //Arrays for points.
    float[] ax = new float[num];
    float[] ay = new float[num];

    //Dimensions of the combined array.
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        ax[i] = 768;
        ay[i] = 1280;
    }

    //Generates frame.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    //Sets frame resolution and other parameters.
    frame.setSize(768,1280);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    RandomWalk panel = new RandomWalk();
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setResizable(false);
   }

   public void paintComponent(Graphics g, int num, int range, int [] ax, int [] ay) {

   //Shift all elements 1 place to the left.
   for(int i = 1; i < num; i++) {
       ax[i-1] = ax[i];
       ay[i-1] = ay[i];
   }

   //Put a new value at the end of the array.
   ax[num-1] += (int) ((Math.random() * -range) + range);
   ay[num-1] += (int) ((Math.random() * -range) + range); 

   //Draw a line connecting the points
   for(int i=1; i<num; i++) {    
     float val = (float) ((i)/num * 204.0 + 51);
     //Sets line color black
     g.setColor(new Color((int) 0));
     g.drawLine(ax[i-1], ay[i-1], ax[i], ay[i]);
   }

   repaint();
}
}
```

Comment: Where is the stochastic computation ? You want to produce two correlated variable (height and width) or just one ? Are you explicitly calling `paintComponent` to draw the lines ?

Comment: I believe the stochastic component is here:

   ax[num-1] += (int) ((Math.random() * -range) + range);
   ay[num-1] += (int) ((Math.random() * -range) + range); 

It changes the x and y values to some random value within the range at each step. Yeah, paintComponent isn't called from within the main method. It should just run. Although it's possible that's where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Ok so that is not a stochastic process :) If your `paintComponent` method is not called anywhere, how could it draw anything ?

Comment: lol that makes sense... But calling it in the main method simply gives me an error. I'm not sure which parameters to pass...

Comment: If I understand, you want to draw a path that follow random point. The path will not change. Is that it ?

Comment: Yeah that is what I am intending to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public class RandomWalk extends JPanel
{
final int   range   = 50;//max space to move in width or height
final int   num     = 50;//number of line-1 to draw
final int[] ax      = new int[num];
final int[] ay      = new int[num];

public RandomWalk(final int width, final int height)
{

    final Random rand = new Random();//better to use Random. Easier to debug since you can set a seed

    // lets set first point in the middle
    ax[0] = width / 2;
    ay[0] = height / 2;

    // generating random point
    for (int i = 1; i < num; i++)
    {
        //make sure that we dont go outside the bound of the panel
        ax[i] = (int) Math.max(0, Math.min(width, ax[i - 1] + ((rand.nextFloat() - .5f) * range)));
        ay[i] = (int) Math.max(0, Math.min(height, ay[i - 1] + ((rand.nextFloat() - .5f) * range)));
    }

}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{

    g.setColor(Color.black);
    for (int i = 1; i < num; i++)
        g.drawLine((int) ax[i - 1], (int) ay[i - 1], (int) ax[i], (int) ay[i]);

}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // Generates frame.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    // Sets frame resolution and other parameters.
    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    RandomWalk panel = new RandomWalk(frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight());
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
     frame.setResizable(false);
}
```

}